# Fix duplicate rows when spliting csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm pretty new at Python and I can't find exactly what I need when searching. I tried a bunch of random things I saw on here with .merge and dropping duplicates but nothing is working for me.

I have a file that has an `Images` column that can have any number of links separated by a comma. My goal here is to create separate columns, with headers, for each index under `Images`. This is what I have so far:

**input.csv**

```
Dealer  Stock#  VIN                 Images      
123      456    1HGCM72624A009649   site.com/001.jpg,site.com/002.jpg,site.com/-003.jpg
123      789    JTHCL5EF9F5072453   site.com/100.jpg,site.com/102.jpg
```

When I use the following code, I get the output.csv file below the code.

**Code**

```
 df = pd.read_csv("input_file.csv", index_col=0, sep='\t', encoding='windows-1252')

 df2 = df['Images'].str.split(',',expand=True)    
 df2.columns = ['Images{}'.format(x+1) for x in df2.columns]

 df = df.join(df2)
 df = df.drop(['Images'], axis=1)

 df.to_csv('output_file.csv')
 print ("The file 'output_file.csv' was created.")
```

**output.csv**

```
Dealer  Stock#  VIN                 Images1           Images2            Images3
123      456    1HGCM72624A009649   site.com/001jpg   site.com/002.jpg   site.com/-003.jpg
123      456    1HGCM72624A009649   site.com/100.jpg  site.com/102.jpg  
123      789    JTHCL5EF9F5072453   site.com/001.jpg  site.com/002.jpg   site.com/-003.jpg
123      789    JTHCL5EF9F5072453   site.com/100.jpg  site.com/102.jpg
```

I really want my file to look like below but I'm not sure where to go from here. Thanks for the help in advance!

```
Dealer  Stock#  VIN                 Images1           Images2            Images3
123      456    1HGCM72624A009649   site.com/001jpg   site.com/002.jpg   site.com/-003.jpg
123      789    JTHCL5EF9F5072453   site.com/100.jpg  site.com/102.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off Chris...

```
df_new = pd.concat([df[['Dealer', 'Stock#', 'VIN']],
                df['Images'].str.split(',',expand=True).rename(columns = lambda x: 
                f"Images{(x+1)}")],
               axis=1).fillna('')
df_new
```

OR pd.merge on index

```
df_new = pd.merge(df[['Dealer', 'Stock#', 'VIN']],
              df['Images'].str.split(',', expand=True).rename(columns = lambda x: f"Images{(x+1)}"),
              how='left',
              left_index=True,
              right_index=True).fillna('')
df_new
```

Comment: OMG David.... Yeah Chris almost got me there but it wasn't renaming headers like it needed to. Now I'll attempt some other stuff on my own. Much thanks, it works!!!

Comment: Awesome @ExQ592 ! Please upvote as well if helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.concat([df,df['Images'].str.split(',',expand=True)], axis=1)
df.columns = ['Dealer','Stock#','VIN','Images','Images1','Images2','Images3']
df.drop(columns=['Images'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: You should describe your code for both the OP as well as for the future readers.